# What link shorteners support captcha before redirect?

Tags: captcha, url-shortening

It seems that all link shortener service advertise themselves as no captcha require. However, I'd like to have the opposite: visitors need to click the captcha before continue. This article [The Top 14 URL Shorteners to Shorten Long Page URLs](https://dynomapper.com/blog/21-sitemaps-and-seo/495-top-14-url-shorteners) doesn't tell me which services support this. SO far I know bitly and tinyurl don't.

Do you know any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it's best to code it yourself? Here are some suggestions: [11 Best PHP URL Shortener Scripts (Free and Premium)](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/10-best-php-url-shortener-scripts--cms-28675)